# gsp form validation and submission for save

Tags: grails, gsp

I am 2 months old to Grails. I was designing a GSP which displays four DropDown from four tables,and in one DropDown I have to fetch the values in concat format.(like name||address).Then,after validating I have to send those values to controller as a collection or json. Anything will do. What is the optimized way to do this, could anyone please suggest. If possible can take two DropDown from two different tables and show in GSP,then validating, then submitting as collection to controller.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do.  The nice thing about the select tag is that it has display text and a separate value so you could have something like this in your controller and/or service:

```
model.myNameOptions = MyTable.list().each { 
   [text: it.name + ' ' + it.address, value: it.value] 
}
```

and in your view you could have:

```
<g:select name="myFieldName" from="${myNameOptions}" 
          optionKey='value' optionValue="text" />
```

As for as submitting this as a collection or json object to the controller, I'm not sure what you mean.  You can have a "multiple" select box which will be submitted and can be views as a list, I believe, in grails.

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks a lot for 1st direction.It solved my concat problem.Only thing remians that I have to validate all the dropdown as not null and send those values to controller.I mean all dropdown should be selected with some values.After clicking on save it should validate dropdown as nto null and sumbit the values to controller action as params.I just want to know the validation and param submission to controller after save button action.It would be better if it can be made through ajax call other than page submit.